pstricks Inside a \marginnote
I am trying to develope an enviroment to create a baseball "At Bat" graphic in the margin.
So I can code something like:
\begin{at-bat}
  \abSingle
  \abFirstStrike{1}
  \abFirstBall{2}
\end{at-bat}
Text descripbing the at bat graphic in the margin

So I defined the following in the preamble:
\usepackage{environ,marginnote}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newcommand{\abFirstStrike}[1]{\rput(0.55,0.3){#1}}
\newcommand{\abFirstBall}[1]{\rput(0.25,0.0){#1}}
\NewEnviron{at-bat}[1]{%
  \marginnote{%
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(1,2)%
      \psset{linewidth=0.125pt}%
      \psline(-1,1)(0,0)(1,1)%
      \psline(-1,1)(0,0)(1,1)%
      \psline(-0.75,0.75)(0,1.5)(0.75,0.75)%
      \psbezier(-1,1)(-0.5,2.3)(0.5,2.3)(1,1)%
      \psset{linewidth=1pt}%
      \BODY%
      \psset{linewidth=0.125pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white}%
      \psline(-1,1)(0,0)(1,1)%
      \psframe(0.7,0.0)(1.0,0.3)% Ball 3
      \psframe(0.4,0.0)(0.7,0.3)% Ball 2
      \psframe(0.1,0.0)(0.4,0.3)% Ball 1
      \psframe(0.7,0.3)(1.0,0.6)% Strike 2
      \psframe(0.4,0.3)(0.7,0.6)% Strike 1
   \end{pspicture}%
  }%
}

So far, so goodish. In xdvi and Okular it renders sort of okay except that the pitch counting numbers are rendered at the bottom centre of the graphic. My first thought was that this must be a featurw of the DVI render.  So I ran `latex-mk --pdflatex' to generated the PDF to see if the text placement correctly. Unfortunatly I got the following error:
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format

I'm useing texlive on Debian and have the following packages installed:
texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-extra-utils texlive-font-utils
texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra
texlive-latex-recommended texlive-luatex texlive-pictures
texlive-plain-generic texlive-pstricks

What as I missing?
My goal here is the simple coding of the At Bat graphic in the margin, and the publishing format needs to be PDF. I'm not wedded to pstricks, but I find I can code for it better and faster (I just can't get my head around xy-pix for example). But I'm open to better solutions if that is the better way forward.
As always, many thanks for your help.
MWE provided as requested:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,marginnote}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newcommand{\abFirstStrike}[1]{\rput(0.85,0.3){#1}}
\newcommand{\abFirstBall}[1]{\rput(0.25,0.0){#1}}
\NewEnviron{at-bat}[1]{%
    \marginnote{%
        \begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(1,2)%
            \psset{linewidth=0.125pt}%
            \psline(-1,1)(0,0)(1,1)%
            \psline(-0.75,0.75)(0,1.5)(0.75,0.75)%
            \psbezier(-1,1)(-0.5,2.3)(0.5,2.3)(1,1)%
            \psset{linewidth=1pt}%
            \BODY%
            \psset{linewidth=0.25pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white}%
            \psframe(0.7,0.0)(1.0,0.3)% Ball 3
            \psframe(0.4,0.0)(0.7,0.3)% Ball 2
            \psframe(0.1,0.0)(0.4,0.3)% Ball 1
            \psframe(0.7,0.3)(1.0,0.6)% Strike 2
            \psframe(0.4,0.3)(0.7,0.6)% Strike 1
        \end{pspicture}%
    %#1%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{at-bat}
        \abSingle
        \abFirstStrike{1}
        \abFirstBall{2}
    \end{at-bat}
    Text describing the at bat graphic in the margin.
\end{document}


Please provide the MWE from \documentclass to \end{document}

@MadyYuvi Added as requested.

Shouldn't you be using extra packages in order for pstricks to be used with pdflatex? Normally you'd use latex+dvips+ps2pdf with pstricks (which compiles just fine). I haven't used pstricks in years, so I do not remember that one also need in order for it to work under pdflatex.

pstricks needs postscript so you can't use it with pdflatex

For a simple image like this just do it once, and save it as a pdf then use it via \includegraphics in your real documents, no need to draw it every time

@DavidCarlisle But in some instances I have other graphcs to draw (like the advances, hit ball trajectory. So I'm going to have to have a pspicture in those cases too, so why not render it every time - doesn't take much compute time these days. I plan for those graphic elements have their own \newcommand definitions in the reamble. With all the pstricks commands in the at-bat environment registration of the various elements is guaranteed.

You can use a package to automatically do latex → dvips → ps2pdf for pspicture environment. If I, e.g., add \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} to your example and run pdflatex--shell-escape foo.tex, it works without problem. With latexmk you also need to activate shell-escape using, e.g., latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S" foo.tex

@daleif Thanks. It was a tool chain issue. I thought I could go stright to PDF without have to first generate the postscript version. If you post this as an answer I'll marke it as the correct solution.

well if you want to render every time and use pdftex you need one of the packages that makes a small document behind the scenes runs it with latex/dvips/ps2pdf in the background and then includes the resulting pdf and that's a high cost. You could draw the graphic in something that works in all engines such as pict2e (close to what you have) or tikz or ....

run the document with lualatex  then you do not need GhostScript and get directly the pdf.

You don't need environ nowadays.
The idea is to produce the picture in a box, which can be forwarded to \marginnote.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\newcommand{\abFirstStrike}[1]{\rput(0.55,0.3){#1}}
\newcommand{\abFirstBall}[1]{\rput(0.25,0.0){#1}}
\newsavebox{\atbatbox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{at-bat}{b}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\atbatbox}
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(1,2)%
      \psset{linewidth=0.125pt}%
      \psline(-1,1)(0,0)(1,1)%
      \psline(-1,1)(0,0)(1,1)%
      \psline(-0.75,0.75)(0,1.5)(0.75,0.75)%
      \psbezier(-1,1)(-0.5,2.3)(0.5,2.3)(1,1)%
      \psset{linewidth=1pt}%
      #1%
      \psset{linewidth=0.125pt,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white}%
      \psline(-1,1)(0,0)(1,1)%
      \psframe(0.7,0.0)(1.0,0.3)% Ball 3
      \psframe(0.4,0.0)(0.7,0.3)% Ball 2
      \psframe(0.1,0.0)(0.4,0.3)% Ball 1
      \psframe(0.7,0.3)(1.0,0.6)% Strike 2
      \psframe(0.4,0.3)(0.7,0.6)% Strike 1
    \end{pspicture}%
  \end{lrbox}\marginnote{\usebox{\atbatbox}}%
}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}  

A picture in the margin
\begin{at-bat}
  %\abSingle % <--- what's this?
  \abFirstStrike{1}
  \abFirstBall{2}
\end{at-bat}
\lipsum[1][1-5]

\end{document}


The picture was obtained with xelatex-unsafe. Or with
latex file && dvips file -o && ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY file.ps

where file is the name of your document.
